# featureFormat() function removes some points?

Tags: python, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I am a little confused about this command as it seems that when I use it some data points are removed from my data set. Here is how:

```
enron_data = pickle.load(open("final_project_dataset.pkl", "r"))

print len(enron_data.keys())
```

and I get :146

Now when I do this:

```
features_list = ["poi", "salary", "exercised_stock_options", "total_payments", "bonus","expenses"]

data = featureFormat(enron_data, features_list)

poi, finance_features = targetFeatureSplit( data )

print len(finance_features)
```

I get 140. Apparently 6 points are not being represented here. What happens?

Answer (score 2):

I just got the answer to this question. It turns out that by default, featureFormat() removes points where all the values are zero. If you don't want to remove them you should pass these arguments : remove_all_zeroes=False, remove_any_zeroes=False. so the code would look like this:

data = featureFormat(enron_data, features_list,remove_all_zeroes=False, remove_any_zeroes=False)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the comments from the method you are referring to...

> remove_all_zeroes = True will omit any data points for which
>               all the features you seek are 0.0 remove_any_zeroes = True will omit any data points for which
>               any of the features you seek are 0.0

remove_all_zeroes: If all the features are zero for a particular data point, there is no point keeping it in the dataset. Hence, it is recommended to leave it as True as is done hy default.

remove_any_zeroes: this is already False by default, so if you omit it from the method call, it will stay False.